# Reading input text / asking for choices

Tags: string, console

I am trying to write a script in which the console asks the user for his name, then tells him/her `Hello "name"`.

Then, it asks `How has your day been`. If the answer is `fine` it should print something. If not, it should print something else.

End of script.

Here is an attempt:
http://pastebin.com/wscQrZhR

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please post the **relevant** portion of your code here, and explain to us how it's not working the way you expect and what specifically we can help you solve. This isn't really a "please find my code at this link and fix it for me" site. We'll be glad to help you with a **specific problem** you're having, but a "what's wrong with my code?" question isn't really appropriate here. The [faq] has more information about how to ask questions here in a way that will improve your chances of getting help. Please [edit] your question and be more specific so we can try and help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you are comparing strings with "==". You shouldn't do this. When you compare strings, "==" checks the object reference, not the content. In other words, if they are not the same object, the statement returns false. You want to use:

```
how.Equals("fine")
```

You might also want to first use:

```
how = how.toLowerCase();
```

or:

```
how.toLowerCase().Equals("fine");
```

To be honest, I'm not sure which is best...

EDIT: I think you want to use how.equalsIgnoreCase("fine")?

However, this shouldn't halt your application. It should move to the else statement. Are you getting an error? Can you be a little more specific about the issue?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was what I needed!
The problem was, that, as you said, I wasn't checking the content of the string properly, and it returned nothing, and it stopped right there, without answering, when I did it with .Equals it worked, I will also try the other way you suggested